# Maui media picker on Windows Platform error

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I have created a very basic MauiApp because I wanted to try the MediaPicker on the Windows Platform.

Thus I copied the code from the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?tabs=windows) and tried to run my application

However if I add `<uap:Capability Name="webcam"/>` to the `Package.appxmanifest` file as suggested in the documentaion, and run the application it gives me the following error:

```
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80080204] error 0xC00CE169: App 
manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 39, Column 
21, Reason: 'webcam' violates enumeration constraint of 'documentsLibrary 
picturesLibrary videosLibrary musicLibrary enterpriseAuthentication 
sharedUserCertificates userAccountInformation removableStorage appointments contacts 
phoneCall blockedChatMessages objects3D voipCall chat'.
The attribute 'Name' with value 'webcam' failed to parse.   MauiApp3
```

So in order to solve this problem I tried to change the capability from `<uap:Capability Name="webcam"/>` to `<DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>`.

In this way I can run the application without errors, but `photo` is always null:

```
public async void TakePhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
    {
        FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
        
        if (photo != null)
        {
            // save the file into local storage
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        }
        else
        {
            // *** IT ALWAYS ENTERS IN THE ELSE CLAUSE ***
            // *** BECAUSE photo IS ALWAYS NULL ***
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Capture is supported but {photo} is null";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The function above is called when I click to this button that I've defined in `MainPage.xaml` file:

```
        <Button 
            x:Name="ImageBtn"
            Text="Take Photo"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Take Image"
            Clicked="TakePhoto"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: I reproduced your problem , it seems a potential issue , consider raising the issue on github : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a old and known bug for WinUI3.
[microsoft/WindowsAppSDK#1034](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1034)

As a workaround you can create a custom mediapicker that inherit everything from the MAUI one for Android, iOS and Catalyst.

Then implement a custom mediapicker for Windows, intheriting all the `Capture...` methods and reimplementing the `CapturePhotoAsync` using a custom class for camera capture:

```cs
public async Task<FileResult> CaptureAsync(MediaPickerOptions options, bool photo)
{
    var captureUi = new CameraCaptureUI(options);

    var file = await captureUi.CaptureFileAsync(photo ? CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo : CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);

    if (file != null)
        return new FileResult(file.Path,file.ContentType);

    return null;
}
```

This is the new `CameraCaptureUI` class:

```cs
public async Task<StorageFile> CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode mode)
{
    var extension = mode == CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo ? ".jpg" : ".mp4";

    var currentAppData = ApplicationData.Current;
    var tempLocation = currentAppData.LocalCacheFolder;
    var tempFileName = $"CCapture{extension}";
    var tempFile = await tempLocation.CreateFileAsync(tempFileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    var token = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.SharedStorageAccessManager.AddFile(tempFile);

    var set = new ValueSet();
    if (mode == CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo)
    {
        set.Add("MediaType", "photo");
        set.Add("PhotoFileToken", token);
    }
    else
    {
        set.Add("MediaType", "video");
        set.Add("VideoFileToken", token);
    }

    var uri = new Uri("microsoft.windows.camera.picker:");
    var result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(uri, _launcherOptions, set);
    if (result.Status == LaunchUriStatus.Success && result.Result != null)
    {
        return tempFile;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also in the Package.appxmanifest add these capabilities:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
```

[Credits for the CameraCapture class](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4710#issuecomment-1017092342)

**Edit:**
Modified code to allow video capturing, [credits here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7660#issuecomment-1153186069)